# Номер последнего из столбцов

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти номер последнего из столбцов, не содержащих ни одного отрицательного элемента. Помогите, пожалуйста, с алгоритмом. Мне не нужно кода, просто подскажите как действовать. Понимаю, что с конца надо начинать идти и по столбцам проходить, но вот как правильно построить - не выходит.

---

Помогите с оптимизацией, пожалуйста.

---

```
const int N=3;
int mas[N][N], i, j;
int x = -1, z = 0;

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        cin>>mas[i][j];

for (i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        if (mas[j][i] < 0)
            z = 1;
    }
    if (z == 0) x = i;
    z = 0;
    if (x && x != -1) i = 0;
}

cout<<"stolbec nomer "<<x+1;
cout<<endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного неясна задача, нужно найти из 0--->n столбец не имеющий отрицательные значения?

1. Создаёшь 2 переменный x(номер
   столбца с отрицательным значением),
   z (управляющая переменная)
2. Проходишь по столбцам и если
   находишь **`значение<0`** то  **`z=1;`**
3. В конце прохода столбца делаешь
   проверку **`z==1`** если да то в x
   записываешь номер столбца и выходишь
   из цикла

---

**UPD** 12.12.2012 22:48(msk)

судя по твоим комментария я неправильно понял задачу  но разница лишь в проверке z==1 или z!=1

1. если тебе нужен последний столбец
   (где нет mas[][]<0) и ты идёшь с конца и
   уже нашел этот столбец то зачем идти
   дальше?
2. раз ты так глупо выходишь из цикла
   то не слышал про **break;** и т.п.
3. тут нужно использовать блок! и не
   мутить всякую хрень...

вот мой пример

```
//массив уже есть и заполнен
int i,j,x=-1,z=-1;
for(i=N-1; i>=0; --i){
   for(j=0; j<N; ++j)
      if(mas[j][i] < 0) z=1;
   if(z != 1) {x=i; break;}
}
if(z == -1) cout<<"в массиве все столбцы имеют отрицательные значения";
else cout<<"последний положительный столбец: "  <<x;
```

по пунктам 1-3: [Учебник по C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/173025/%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c) хотя я бы посоветовал сначала [link 1](http://www.mini-soft.ru/soft/vba/r_2.php), [link 2](http://teacher.dn-ua.com/algoritm/Part1.pdf)

Comment: int main()
{
 const int N=3;
 int mas[N][N], i, j;
 int x = -1, z = 0;

 for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
   cin>>mas[i][j];

 for (i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
 {
  for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
  {
   if (mas[j][i] < 0)
    z = 1;
  }
  if (z == 0) x = i;
  z = 0;
  if (x && x != -1) i = 0;
 }
 
 cout<<"stolbec nomer "<<x+1;
 cout<<endl;
system ("pause");
return 0;
}


Спасибо вот так сделал. Помогите пожалуйста теперь упростить мои изврашения)

Comment: а вот тут ты что вообще  делаешь? порядок опиши пожалуйста! (своими словами...)

    if (z == 0) x = i;
    z = 0;
    if (x && x != -1) i = 0;

Comment: Ну если z = 0, т е если в столбце нет отрицательных чисел, то фиксируем номер. z обнуляю для того чтобы, когда мы прошлись по столбцу с отрицательным, а после по столбцу с положительным z не остался единицей, вообщем чтобы он не остался единицей после прохода по не положительному. Ну а дальше такое условие, потому что х=0 может быть индексов нужным мне, т е индексом столбца (первого).

Comment: @RubyNub 

>  Ну а дальше такое условие, потому что
> х=0 может быть индексов нужным мне, т
> е индексом столбца (первого).

из этой фразы ничего непонятно... 
что произойдёт если убрать строчку:

    if (x && x != -1) i = 0;

какая ошибка вылезет? что не будет работать? при каких условиях не будет работать?

Comment: Будет не верно работать. Допустим, если в матрице(3х3) первый отриц, а вторые два положительные, то он выведет столбец номер 2(с учетом прибавленной единицы для наглядности), а должен вывести номер 3

Comment: Эта строчка отвечает за выход, когда мы уже нашли нужный, так как я иду с конца, то первый найденный - нужный мне стольец

Answer (score 2):

Ну, всё же просто.

Для начала заведите функцию, которая определяет по номеру столбца, есть ли в нём отрицательные элементы. Это должно быть просто.

Затем, идёте от номера последнего столбца (не забудьте, в C++ индексы начинаются с 0, поэтому максимальный индекс = N - 1, где N -- количество столбцов. Проверяйте столбец подготовленной функцией. Останавливайтесь либо если нашли нужный столбец, либо если индекс ушёл в отрицательные значения.

Если индекс таки ушёл в отрицательные значения, нужного столбца не нашлось, в противном случае у вас есть номер столбца, на котором закончился пробег алгоритма.

Answer (score 2):

[[@RubyNub](/users/6638/rubynub)](/users/6638/rubynub), Вы программу-то уже фактически сделали. Вот Ваша

```
for (i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        if (mas[j][i] < 0)
            z = 1;
    }
    if (z == 0) x = i;
    z = 0;
    if (x && x != -1) i = 0;
}

cout<<"stolbec nomer "<<x+1;
```

Чуть-чуть модифицируем ее, достаточно одного признака z. Номер столбца (с нуля) в конце будет в переменной i.

z обнуляется внутри цикла по столбцам и остается нулевым, если в столбце нет отрицательных чисел. Сам цикл по столбцам работает пока  в очередном столбце есть хоть одно отрицательное число.

```
for (i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (z = 0, j = 0; !z && j < N; j++)
    {
        if (mas[j][i] < 0)
            z = 1;
    }
    if (!z) break;
}

if (!z)
  cout<<"OK. column " << i << " is positive\n";
else
  cout << "Fail\n";
```

Обратите внимание, что цикл по строкам столбца (по j) прерывается, как только найдено отрицательное число. Вот, собственно и все.

Answer (score 1):

Создаете переменную `(int num_col=-1);`
Далее бежишь по столбцу в цикле, если нашел отрицательное - то `break` и переходишь к следующему столбцу, если столбец закончился, то `num_col = номеру столбца`.

Answer (score 0):

Не проверял особо и демал, но думаю суть ясна.

```
    int64_t mass[] = {
           0,-1, 2,
           3, 4, 5,
           6, 7, 8
    };

    const uint64_t size = 3;
    uint64_t stat[3] = {1, 1, 1};
    int64_t * begin = mass, * end = (mass+size*size);
    while(begin != end) {
      if(*begin < 0) 
        stat[((begin - mass) % size)] = 0;
      ++begin;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d%d%d\n", stat[0], stat[1], stat[2]);
```

Если зафейлил и что-то не понял - не пинайте сильно - я дно в этом.